# monacaから条件を指定してmBaaSの値を取得する方法

Tags: javascript, monaca, baas

monacaを使用して、以下のような方法でNifty mBaaSの
データストアに保存されているデータを取得しています。

```
var Score = self.ncmb.DataStore(クラス名);
Score.order("score", true)
.include("name")
.limit(10)
.fetchAll()
.then(function(results){
//取得データを画面に表示
}
```

今度、データストアのクラスに持っている"createdate"を条件として絞り込みを行いたいのですが、
どのように記述すれば宜しいでしょうか？

取得にしたいのは、以下の2パターンです。
① "createdate"が本日中のデータ
② "createdate"が今月中のデータ

http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/datastore/basic_usage_monaca.html#/Monaca/
リンクにある『基本的なクエリのオペランド』の欄を調べたんですが
"createdate"の日付の形式が『yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000+09:00』な事もあり、
具体的な方法が分からず質問させていただきました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/UserCommunity/issues/467 マルチポスト

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/37798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`greaterThanOrEqualTo()` `>=` と `lessThanOrEqualTo()` `<=` で開始日時と終了日時を指定すれば抽出できます。
日時は「[REST API リファレンス 5.1 日付](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/rest/common/format.html#%E6%97%A5%E4%BB%98)」に記載されているとおりに設定します。

日時は[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)を使用しています。
①本日中のデータの場合、`startOf()` `endOf()`で`"day"`を指定します。
②今月中のデータの場合、`"month"`を指定します。

```
var Score = self.ncmb.DataStore(クラス名);
var startDate = moment().startOf("day");    // 開始日時
var endDate = moment().endOf("day");        // 終了日時
Score.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createDate", { "__type": "Date", "iso": startDate.toISOString() })
    .lessThanOrEqualTo("createDate", { "__type": "Date", "iso": endDate.toISOString() })
    .order("score", true)
    .include("name")
    .limit(10)
    .fetchAll()
    .then(function(results) {
        //取得データを画面に表示
    });
```

Comment: 無事に条件の絞り込みが行えました。
丁寧に教えて頂き、本当にありがとうございました。